# Ubuntu 20.04 and Microsoft SQL Server connection problem

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, unixodbc

I am trying to connect SQL Server from Ubuntu 20.04 with PHP PDO, I am facing an error message stating:

> Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[08001] SQLDriverConnect: 10054 [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: Error code 0x2746 in /var/www/testsite/sqlsrv.php

Code:

```
$db = new PDO("odbc:Driver=ODBCSQLServer;Server=derver.name\\instance;Port=10000;Database=dbname;charset=utf8;MARS_Connection=yes", "user", "password");
```

The same error happens both from PDO with ODBC and with SqlSrv.

I have similar connection with CentOS 8 which works just fine.

From Google I have encountered some similar problems, which connect the problem with encryption support but . I am not administering the SQL Server but the administrator has said that the encryption is not set on SQL Server side. As there are a multitude of apps on different databases on the same SQL Server setting encryption on the server might cause a major havoc for all the other apps. SQL Server version is 2012.

The server is a very plain Ubuntu 20.04 server, I have only added LEMP stack and extensions/drivers for PDO (sqlsrv and ODBC) and sql server driver (v. 17). As it is currently for testing Ubuntu Server, I may try basically whatever to solve the problem. (The main reason behind this test is the RedHat decision to undermine CentOS)

Any ideas how to proceed?

Comment: Sharing your code would be a start. "Uncaught exception" with no code, no [mre], isn't going to help many of users here, if any at all

Comment: The code example added

Comment: Isn't `charset=utf8` a MySQL thing?

Comment: It may be, but at least there hasn't been any problems when using it on other server(s) and removing it didn't cause any change in this problem